# Maria db primary id trouble

Tags: mysql, mariadb, primary-key

I have  to do uni project for database it is about medical center. Therefore, I made a conceptual and physical model, but now I have to model the database.

So i have relations  `patients`, `doctorID`, `general-practitioners`, `doctors-specialists`, `polyclinic` and so on. The idea of my professor is that  relation `doctorID` (that relation will only have doctorID atribute) give `ID` for both `general-practitioners` (ID,name,phone) and `doctors-specialists` (ID,name, speciality).

Now my problem is how to set the `ID` for `general-practiotioners` to be between 0 - 100 and for the `doctors-specialist` to be from 101 to 200. In addition, how to make that automated if someone starts writing new `doctor-specialist` that in my foreign/primary key attribute that he shows only from 101-200.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: why do you want to differentiate with id? can't you use the doctor_type field?

Comment: @Melody I am looking now solution on the internet. to try something.@Danyal Sandeelo well i was thinking about that field but to put it in the relation doctor specialist or in the doctorID relation?

Comment: I would say that 'general practice' *is* a speciality

Comment: In general, if you find yourself worrying about the value of a primary key id, then you can be confident that there's something very wrong with your data model.

Comment: @Strawberry yes general practice is a speciality but i need to make difference in between  gp doctors that we go every time we  are ill and those doctors where we go after gp see some bigger problems with your body, like cancer, or i don't know pneumonia or kidney problem.

Comment: [Don't use smart keys.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082143/3404097) Time to read an introduction to information modeling & relational database design. Also time to google the manuals re 'auto increment'.

Comment: I cannot see why you would need to make this distinction. It sounds like a bad idea.