# When creating a table using SQL, a variable student-type can be either post-grad or under-grad. What data type should I use?

Tags: mysql, schema, relational

This is what I have now. I have done a check for DECIMAL() using BETWEEN AND. Was wondering if it is possible to do the same for VARCHAR()

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
student_number      CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
first_name          VARCHAR(50)     NULL,
last_name           VARCHAR(50)     NULL,
date_of_birth       DATE            NULL,
student_type        VARCHAR(20)     NULL,
CONSTRAINT student_pkey PRIMARY KEY (student_number),
CONSTRAINT student_check1 CHECK (student_type POSTGRADUDATE_STUDENT OR UNDERGRADUATE_STUDENT));
```

Comment: Why not just use an ENUM column type?

Comment: Enum is a good suggestion here.  Beyond that, MySQL does not enforece check constraints, so the constraint you wrote won't be used.  The only other option would be to enforce using a trigger, but that's sort of ugly.  I'd go with enum, which also has the benefit of reducing the amount of space needed to store the `student_type`.

Comment: Oh, yes I could. Thank you!

Comment: Note that ENUM will always permit an empty string. And it sorts by the internal code. Also consider switching to MariaDB, which supports CHECKs in the latest version.

Comment: What are you mentioning DECIMAL & BETWEEN for? What does "the same" mean? Exactly what is it you can't find out about CHECK? PS This column is a "type tag" or type "variant tag".

Comment: In response to philipxy, an example would be DECIMAL(2)  and writing a CHECK constraint BETWEEN 1 AND 99. So, what I was trying to imply was having to check if it's either post-grad or under-grad by setting given values, like how I have given the range 1-99.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server "pseudo/synthetic" composite Id(key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149354/sql-server-pseudo-synthetic-composite-idkey)

Comment: Hi. Please clarify via editing your post, not via comments. That is an anitpattern called [smart keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082143/3404097). You have a case of [database/SQL subtypes/hierarchies/inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082143/3404097). Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers.  If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. PS Google 'stackexchange comment notifications' re "@". Note MySQL doesn't *enforce* CHECK constraints.