# super-type subtype discriminator in Primary key and design simplicty?

Tags: sql, database-design, subtype, supertype

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes) great answer by  [PerformanceDBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484814/performancedba):

The referenced answer approaches the problem of supertype subtype by :

1. using a Discriminator in the base-type ( which could be constrained by using FK and lookup table for **TYPE**)
2. creating a simple **FUNCTION** to check exclusivity which gets called using **CHECK** constraint in the subtype.

**My question :**
if the discriminator is part of the primary key of the **base-type** and **a User Defined Function is USED to check for exclusivity** , would a design like this break any relational design or would it make the design simpler ( given that the PK is not multi valued of course) ?

Here is an example for illustration:

| ProductID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 120001 | This product is Car ( starts with **120**) |
| 150001 | This Product is Boat (starts with **150**) |
| 160001 | This Product is Jet (starts with **160**) |

can call a function that checks for the ID of product and insert this into the desired table ( Jet table , Boat Table or Car table ) based on the ID?

if that is the case , can I get rid of the Discriminator column and the look up table too ?

is there any shortcoming of this approach ?

**UPDATE to illustrate the two design approaches :**

[image: Illustration of Question]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server "pseudo/synthetic" composite Id(key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149354/sql-server-pseudo-synthetic-composite-idkey)

Comment: 1) As long as you stick to breaking 1NF, I can't help you, sorry.  2) Please read the **[Subtype](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf)** document.

Comment: sorry , How am I breaking the 1NF in this case ? the ID is an atomic single /Value of the same data type of INT. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Read my Answer, carefully.  "120" is one datum `ProductType`, "001" is a second datum `ProductNo`. "120001" is a combination, it breaks 1NF.  *"the ID is an atomic single /Value"* is false, it is not atomic.

Comment: thank you and please bare with me as I am trying to learn this , but what if this actually how the scooters are identified in real world ? there is a plate and a sticker that comes with the scooter it self that identifies it this way. I should have mentioned this earlier.

Comment: The real world is physical, but the perception of the real world must, needs be, logical.  If that is the plate, then the thing is not a `ScooterID`, but some form of serial number, which is made up of `ScooterType` plus `SerialNo`, each of which is an atom, the conglomeration of which is not an atom.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. Give a legend with an image. This site uses white & black background. So please no images with transparency. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Put everything but only what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Relate it to your question. Quote with credit & format as a quote. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Comment: @Ayed Please join me in a [Chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252187/scooter-serial-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *is there any shortcoming of this approach* ?

Yes.

You have broken 1NF:

> **First Normal Form**
> Each domain (column) must be Atomic, that is, indivisible
> with regard to the SQL Platform (Datatypes).

Your `ProductID` is a conglomeration thing that is made up from two atomic things:
    `ProductType  CHAR(1) -- {C, B, J, ...}`
and some number within that, say
    `ProductNo    INT`.

At the point of your table (which is not described) in the data hierarchy, the PK is an ordinary Relational composite key:
    `( ProductType, ProductNo )`.
not:
    `ProductID`.

Now you don't need a Subtype cluster *in that table*.

But I suspect you need exclusivity pivoting on some other concept: if so, you need to post a model of all the tables related to this issue.