# Mix complex Primary Key in table

Tags: sql-server

I got a database project as full semester homework from my university, in one of my tables is it possible to have a primary key in following format
001SALS201812101 auto increment
Actually this primary key defines like following

```
001 - Branch Code
SALS - TRN Type
2018 - Current Year
122 - days of the year
101 - the auto increment number
```

can anybody tell me how to make such a primary key

Comment: MySql is not SQL Server. Those are two different products. In any case, keeping multiple values in a single database column is never a good idea. A primary key does not have to be a single column, it can be a composite key spanning over multiple columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for response, If I make composite primary key in a table then can I combine them and use all of them as a foreign key in another table single column, I will be glad if you give me an example

Comment: There are examples in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Personally, I prefer not to construct keys that have any meaning beyond the internal scope of the database.

Comment: Is the auto-increment portion of the key a serial number in the range 000-999, with each combination key components having an independent sequence?

Comment: Please tell exactly what you were told to do. You seem to be saying that you want a string-valued column that concatenates strings per other columns. [That is a design anti-pattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454136/3404097) Or could you have been asked for a *composite* key & no added columns. PS Please clarify by editing your post, not via comments. And which is it--MySQL/MySQLi or SQL Server? Please edit your tags.

Comment: @GhufranAtaie Why would you make your life difficult, and create a complicated primary key???  Stick with simple integer primary key.

Comment: @philipxy I have edited my post tags, and what I want exactly it written in my post also I don't know what to call this procedure composite key or concatenating the columns I just want to get it done, either using all columns or making one column as primary key including all parts such as branchcode-transactionType-CurrentYear-CurrentDay-ReferenceNo
like 001-PUR-18-122-001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something I would recommend doing in the table. But rather in a view dependent on the table.

> Let the db do what it does well, that being, a standard auto-incrementing `integer` as the primary key.

Should you need to ensure **uniqueness** of the combination, simply add a unique index/key ([SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) / [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html)).

Below is an example, using SQL Server:

```
create table Sales (
    Id int identity primary key
    ,BranchCode int
    ,TRNType varchar(25)
    ,Year int
    ,DaysOfYear int
);

create unique index ux_sales_key on Sales (BranchCode, TRNType, Year, DaysOfYear);
go
```

> Note that SQL Server supports [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) as of 2016. This would also solve your problem, and in the table itself.

And now the same table structure in MySQL

```
create table Sales (
    Id int auto_increment primary key
    ,BranchCode int
    ,TRNType varchar(25)
    ,Year int
    ,DaysOfYear int
    ,unique key (BranchCode, TRNType, Year, DaysOfYear)
);
```

To formulate your "composite key" use a view similar to the following:

```
create view vSales
as
    select
        concat(BranchCode, TRNType, Year, DaysOfYear, Id) as SomeCompositeKey
        -- the rest of your cols go here
    from
        Sales;
go
```