# Is posible on insert query use auto-increment to concatenate with string for column value?

Tags: mysql

Is posible on insert query use `auto-increment` to concatenate with string for one column value?

The current `AUTO-INCREMENT is = 89` name columns `pkey`

**Example query string:**

```
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (`ProcessCod`, `ProcessName`, ) VALUES(CONCAT('f-pdf-',AUTO-INCREMENT), 'Text-Description');
```

All in one query???

**update i think on a string like this:**

```
INSERT INTO `Tbl` (
    `ProcessCod`, 
    `ProcessName`)
VALUES(
    SELECT CONCAT('f-pdf-',`AUTO_INCREMENT`) 
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'INFO'
    AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'Tbl',
    'Text-Description'
);
```

**the scope of my question is around the use of auto-increment (no primary key) to fill a column with it and concatenating with a dinamic string not a static prefix.**

Comment: You could do it with an ON INSERT trigger on the table; but not within the insert statement itself. _But why not just SELECT the concatenation when needed?_

Comment: @Uueerdo i think on use the select but not working correclty check update...

Comment: I meant just concat in normal selects when needed, not insert with a select abusing the information_schema.table.

Comment: its like i need ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Comment: @stickybit it is not the same because: 'p-pdf-' can change depending on the extension. and the column related not is the primary key.

Comment: [Smart keys are an anitpattern.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28454136/3404097)

Comment: this not smartkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved with this code:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl (
    ProcessCod, 
    ProcessName
)VALUES(
    (SELECT CONCAT('f-pdf-',`AUTO_INCREMENT`) 
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'INFO'
    AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'Tbl'),
    'Text-Description'
);
```

it was necessary to place the Select in parentheses so that it works correctly.

Comment: Yes, subselects always have their own parentheses.

Comment: Sometimes, an idea just sounds bad.