# Can I create a composite key with an extra character?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, composite-primary-key

I'm building a new DB using MySQL to store lessons learned across a variety of projects. When we talk about this in the office, we refer to lessons by the Project Number and Lesson Number, i.e. PR12-81, where PR12 refers to the project and 81 refers to the specific lesson within that project. I want the primary key in my DB to have a hyphen in it as well.

When defining a composite key in SQL, I can make it reference the project and lesson but without the hyphen, i.e. PR1281. I've also considered creating a separate column of data type CHAR(1), putting a hyphen in every row and delcaring that the PK is made of 3 columns.

Is there another way that I can specify the primary key to be formatted in the preferred way?

Comment: If the key is composite then leave out the hyphen and add it back when you write a view or query for the UI layer. It doesn't need to be stored. IMHO.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper database model for a user feedback system (an interesting case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364258/proper-database-model-for-a-user-feedback-system-an-interesting-case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your table's primary key be a nonsensical auto-increment number with no "meaning" whatsoever.  Then, within that table, define *two* columns:  `project_number` and `lesson_number`.  If the two need to be unique, define a `UNIQUE` index encompassing the two fields.

*Don't(!)* create database keys which embed information into them, even if the business does so.  If the business needs to refer to strings like `PR12`, so be it ... create a column to store the appropriate value, or use a one-to-many table.  Use indexes as needed to enforce uniqueness.

Notice(!) that I've now described *four* columns:

1. The auto-increment based "actual" primary key, which contains no information.
2. The `project_number` column, probably a foreign key to a `projects` table.
3. Ditto the `lesson_number`.  (With a `UNIQUE` composite *index* if needed.)
4. The column (or table) which contains "the string that the business uses."

Over time, business practices *do* change.  And someday you just might .. no, you **will...** ... encounter a "business-used string" that was *incorrectly* assigned by the human-beings who do such things!  Your database design needs to gracefully handle this.  The schema I've described is so-called **third-normal form.**  Do a Google-search on "normal forms" if you haven't already.