# Composite primary key vs a unique constraint in a multi tenant database system

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm working on a multi tenant system, so there is a `organization` table that has relations to most of the other tables. So for most of my queries I query for the `tableId` (the primary key) of that table and the signed in `organizationId`. Or just for the `organizationId` - to get all that customers record(s).

To improve performance I guess I could use a unique constraint on the `tableId` + `organizationId` combination? But would be an even better option in this case to just set up the primary key as a composite key of the `tableId` + `organizationId` combination?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper database model for a user feedback system (an interesting case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364258/proper-database-model-for-a-user-feedback-system-an-interesting-case)

Comment: [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932)
[Re SQL "performance".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196511/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE PKTABLE (
    tid int,
    id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (tid, id)
);

CREATE TABLE FKTABLE (
    tid int,
    id int,
    fk_id_del_set_null int,
    fk_id_del_set_default int DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (tid, fk_id_del_set_null) REFERENCES PKTABLE ON DELETE SET NULL (fk_id_del_set_null),
    FOREIGN KEY (tid, fk_id_del_set_default) REFERENCES PKTABLE ON DELETE SET DEFAULT (fk_id_del_set_default)
);

INSERT INTO PKTABLE
    VALUES (1, 0),
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2);

INSERT INTO FKTABLE
    VALUES (1, 1, 1, NULL),
    (1, 2, NULL, 2);

DELETE FROM PKTABLE
WHERE id = 1
    OR id = 2;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    FKTABLE
ORDER BY
    id;
```

Primary key(tid,id) means both column cannot be NULL.
Unique(tid,id) means it accept (tid null,id null), (tid not null, id null), (tid null, id not null). [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=72febf44ce9f1b7495894fa23029fcc6)

Other than that, all the same. Primary key will create index, unique contsraint will also create index. see [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html)

So overall, if you use primary key, you don't need to care about both two column will be null or not.
And in pg15 ([link](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=d6f96ed94e73052f99a2e545ed17a8b2fdc1fb8a)), in foreign key you can

```
FOREIGN KEY (tid, fk_id_del_set_null) REFERENCES PKTABLE ON DELETE SET NULL (fk_id_del_set_null)
```

Which means that you tenant_id will always exists in all the table related to that tenant_id.